# How do you publish a draft on Wordpress

Tags: functions

I can't work out how to publish a draft.  I go to preview, to check everything's ok, and then there doesn't seem to be any option to do anything more.

Comment: Not all users are allowed to publish posts. Sometimes an editor has to check your post first.

Answer (score 1):

The preview usually opens in a new tab/window for convenience. Even **before** going to preview, there should be a blue 'Publish' button present in the same area as the 'Preview' button, "the same area" being the Publish metabox.

Below is what the Publish metabox looks like in the latest version of Wordpress (3.5.1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

see the preview so that you understand how it looks then you can publish, the preview can be opened in a new tab with responsive nature i.e., draft is displayed then you may publish in future